# Fix invalid polygon in Shapely

Tags: python, geometry, shapely

Shapely defines a Polygon as invalid if any of its segments intersect, including segments that are colinear. Many software packages will create a region or area with a "cutout" as shown here which has colinear segments:

[image]

```
>>> pp = Polygon([(0,0), (0,3), (3,3), (3,0), (2,0), 
                  (2,2), (1,2), (1,1), (2,1), (2,0), (0,0)])
>>> pp.is_valid
WARNING:shapely.geos:Self-intersection at or near point 2 0
False
```

Naturally, the cutout can be implemented natively in Shapely, or this same geometry can be implemented as two valid polygons, but if I only have the list of points shown above, is there an easy to "fix" this (create valid geometry from this list of points)?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I found a solution that works for the specific case given:

```
>>> pp2 = pp.buffer(0)
>>> pp2.is_valid
True
>>> pp2.exterior.coords[:]
[(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 3.0), (3.0, 3.0), (3.0, 0.0), (2.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0)]
>>> pp2.interiors[0].coords[:]
[(2.0, 1.0), (2.0, 2.0), (1.0, 2.0), (1.0, 1.0), (2.0, 1.0)]
```

Comment: I find that this buffer( 0 ) method works in general for fixing polygons with coincident lines among sub-polygons. This is very useful. Do you know of a place where this trick is officially recommended/sanctioned?

Comment: This method did not fix my issue: I had some self-intersecting multipolygons.

Comment: You need to be a little careful with the `buffer(0)` technique. We've had bowtie cases where it destroyed the big part of the polygon and left just a small bowtied corner. YMMV.

Comment: For me it made a valid polygon but it no longer had any .exterior.coords so it still did not work for a .within(polygon) analysis.

Comment: Does anyone knows if a solution exists for this now? As much as i undertand @AidanKane didn't recommended the `buffer(0)`.

Comment: @JoséRojas It's.....complicated. The solution we ended up using is to break invalid polygons into a map of valid polygons using shapely.ops.polygonize. We then iterated of each one and decided if it was inside or outside using winding rules. We then union the included ones together.

Comment: @JoséRojas See my new answer, looks like shapely have added a function to do this! https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#validation.make_valid

Comment: buffer(0) also behaves different on different os (see my answer)!

Answer (score 15):

Shapely implemented a solution for this. Through pip you can use any shapely version >= 1.8a3 and import this way:

```py
from shapely.validation import make_valid
```

The current version of shapely available via pip and conda includes the `make_valid` function. If you need to install an older version of shapely, you can use the shapely implementation as shown below:

```py
def make_valid(ob):

    from shapely.geometry.base import geom_factory
    from shapely.geos import lgeos
    
    if ob.is_valid:
        return ob

    return geom_factory(lgeos.GEOSMakeValid(ob._geom))
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the following exception is raised:

AttributeError: 'LGEOS360' object has no attribute 'GEOSMakeValid'

Any objections, how to solve this? I would like to use the make_valid function but on a stable release (and no alpha release) ...

Comment: make_valid is better than a buffer(0) which can change the geometry completely. The the doc's [second example](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#id32) in particular is a good example to test both methods.

Answer (score 5):

Untested, but it appears that Shapely have added a function to support this now.

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#validation.make_valid

Answer (score 4):

simplest solution

```
new_polygon = pp.buffer(0)
new_polygon.is_valid
```

maybe it would be work.

Answer (score 3):

This is my first attempt at a fix geometry function. I had to handle the special case where a polygons are converted to multipolygons, where `make_valid` doesn't work b/c `len(make_valid(feature)) !=1`.

```py
from shapely.validation import make_valid

def fix_geom(in_feature):

    # avoid changing original geodf
    in_feature = in_feature.copy(deep=True)    
        
    # drop any missing geometries
    in_feature = in_feature[~(in_feature.is_empty)]
    
    # Repair broken geometries
    for index, row in in_feature.iterrows(): # Looping over all polygons
        if row['geometry'].is_valid:
            next
        else:
            fix = make_valid(row['geometry'])

            try:
                in_feature.loc[[index],'geometry'] =  fix # issue with Poly > Multipolygon
            except ValueError:
                in_feature.loc[[index],'geometry'] =  in_feature.loc[[index], 'geometry'].buffer(0)
    return in_feature
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used the .buffer(0) method a lot, but it gave different results on Windows and on Linux. Therefore if you encounter such a problem, remember that:

**Warning**: The .buffer(0) function of shapely may behave different on different operating systems, i.e. Windows and Linux. I had examples, where on Linux an empty Polygon is returned while on Windows the correct non-empty Polygon is returned!

This problem took me days to solve, that's why I want to add that as an answer (my suggested edit to the accepted answer was sadly rejected).