# Shapely polygon creates straight lines between points where it shouldn't

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, shapely

I'm using `shapely` within Python. I created a polygon using coordinates; however, when I plot it, it creates random straight lines between points where it should not.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

And here is what I want the perimeter to look like (without the fill):

[image]

Here's the code I'm using to create the polygon and plot it:

```
poly_coords = coords[['lon','lat']]
poly_coords = poly_coords.values.tolist()
poly = Polygon(poly_coords)

x,y = poly.exterior.xy
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Is there something I'm missing that's causing the random lines between points to be created?

Comment: Can you add `coords` to your question so it can be reproduced?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's thousands of coordinates. I'm not sure how to upload all of them here.

Comment: Try [fixing the geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833344/fix-invalid-polygon-in-shapely)

Comment: You’re probably working with a multipolygon, not a polygon.

Comment: Use online service https://mapshaper.org/ to check/edit/simplify/export for more suitable  data set.